# SSRS Export to Excel

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report with Hyperlinks to 2 other SSRS report, through the Actions tab I am passing a parameter value to those hyperlinks, main report is exported to Excel and link is there everything is fine.

"=http://[SERVER]/[RSSERVER]/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?[REPORTName]&rs:FORMAT=EXCEL&[ParemterName]=" &[ParameterValue]

When I myself click any of the hyperlink after exporting the report in Excel it opens a browser window and downloads (in my Download folder) the linked rdl in excel format with its actual rdl name .XLS and that's the expected correct operation without giving me any security warning in Excel and I can click on other hyperlink to other report.

But for all other users when they click the hyperlink first they receive a security warning about opening a harmful link and when user clicks OK it opens the link but the filename is ReportViewer.XLS so if user do not close that file and click on other hyperlink it will not download it because ReportViewer.XLS is already opened.

I have checked with couple of users their Excel Options are identical to mine.

I am not sure what is the causing this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked the setting in Excel using File=>Options=>Trust Center. There are a lot of options in there relating to opening external content etc.

Comment: I cross checked with another user and compared Trust Center settings with mine, they are all identical, even checked Trusted sites under Internet Options under control panel, they are all same.